# Scroll list of columns vertically with fixed header but scroll list and header horizontally

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jefftg/1chmyppm/

The orange header columns and the white list rows scroll together horizontally, which is desired. However, I want the white list rows to scroll vertically with the orange header fixed at the top. They currently don't. I'm looking for this to work in modern browsers with HTML5/CSS3.

**css**

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
}

.header-cell {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.data-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-row {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.data-row-cell {
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header-cell">A</div>
  <div class="header-cell">B</div>
  <div class="header-cell">C</div>
  <div class="header-cell">D</div>
</div>

<div class="data-container">
  <div class="data-row">
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      A1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      B1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      C1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      D1
    </div>
  </div>

  ......

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by simply adding height: 558px to .data-container: jsfiddle.net/jefftg/1chmyppm/2

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pure CSS and you don't need JavaScript.

I've modified your JSFiddle to work the way you are requesting: https://jsfiddle.net/48386nvn/3/

Essentially, `.header-container` needs to be positioned absolute relative to the `.container` element:

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* added this: */
  position: relative;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  /* added these: */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The above-mentioned CSS will stick the orange header where you want it and maintain the width you need it to be.

Next, you'll need to make the data scrollable, which is done by doing the following calculation:

```
height: heightOfParentContainer - heightOfHeaderRow;
```

The header cell height is 40px (42px when respecting the borders) It also needs a `margin-top` equal to the height of the header row:

```
.data-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added these: */
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 560px;
}
```

This should make sure that the header row is not overlapping the data container, and that the height of the data takes up the rest of the space of the overall container.

Comment: I was able to get the desired result by simply adding `height: 558px` to `.data-container`: https://jsfiddle.net/jefftg/1chmyppm/2/

Comment: Now my problem is the vertical scrollbar for the `.data-container` div isn't visible unless the `.container` div is fully scrolled to show the right edge of the `.data-container` div.

Comment: Right now, the only way I have to fix my vertical scrollbar problem is to use Javascript to keep the width of the `.data-container` div set to the `.container` div's scrollLeft + clientWidth. I'm wondering if there is a css-only solution.

Comment: I believe scrollbar visibility is a different question altogether. Are you using a Mac? Scrollbars are hidden by default on Mac. You may want to implement a scrollbar plugin if having visible scrollbars is important. One way to alleviate this UX issue without using JS is make the `.data-container` height and width the right size so that it looks like it should be scrolled—having parts of the last cells cut off should be clear that the user should scroll.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add the overflow to every element, just the elements that need scrolling,

all I did is gave your `.data-container`a `display:block` and a certain height so that the `overflow-y:auto` can work, you can change the height with what you see fits in your page.

this here shows my solution, I hope it helps.

```js
$(".header-container").scroll(function() {
  var scrollPercentage = 100 * this.scrollLeft / (this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth);
  $(".data-container").scrollTop(scrollPercentage);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.header-cell {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.data-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
.data-row {
  display: block;
}
.data-row-cell {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header-cell">A</div>
  <div class="header-cell">B</div>
  <div class="header-cell">C</div>
  <div class="header-cell">D</div>
</div>

<div class="data-container">
  <div class="data-row">
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      A1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      B1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      C1
    </div>
    <div class="data-row-cell">
      D1
    </div>
  </div>

  ......

</div>
```

Comment: you may want to try running your snippet before posting the answer... it doesn't work, the header columns scroll separately from the rest horizontally, while the OP wanted them to scroll together...

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to that, I'll modify my code right away :)

Comment: @Sybarium Changing `display` in `.data-container` from `inline-block` to `block` causes the cells in each row to be displayed vertically instead of horizontally. Also, it turns out that the jQuery is not necessary. The key point is to set a height for `.data-container.` If you update your answer to reflect these changes, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Sybarium Here's what I have currently with a height added to `.data-container`: https://jsfiddle.net/jefftg/66u6g7m7/. This works, but the one problem I now have is when scrolling the rows vertically, the scrollbar doesn't appear on the right unless the entire grid is scrolled all the way to the right horizontally. Adding a width to `.data-container` shows the scrollbar when vertically scrolling and no horizontal scrolling has occurred, but when scrolling horizontally, the rows are cut off. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @JeffG Superb, I misunderstood what your goal from this, now I see the full picture, I hope you put your solution as an answer so we can vote it up and your question gets answered, thank you and have a nice day :)